# Update specific line of a txt file

Tags: bash, terminal, append, line

Using terminal, I have this output "Date.IPLOG"
How can I update/add this output to a specific line of another txt overwriting only that previous line content?

output `Date.IPLOG`
the line `5000 = IP changed Date.IPLOG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose your starting file is:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
```

And suppose you want to change line 3 to `NewValue`.  In that case, run:

```
$ awk -v new="NewValue" -v line=3 'NR==line{$0=new} 1' file
1
2
NewValue
4
5
```

That displays the new version to stdout.  To change `file`, run:

```
awk -v new="NewValue" -v line=3 'NR==line{$0=new} 1' file >tmp && mv tmp file
```

Or, if you have `gawk` (GNU awk), we can simplify the above to:

```
awk -i inplace -v new="NewValue" -v line=3 'NR==line{$0=new} 1' file
```

#### How it works

1. `-v new="NewValue"` creates an awk variable `new`.
2. `-v line=3` creates an awk variable `line`.
3. If the current line number, `NR`, is `line`, then `NR==line{$0=new}` changes the contents of the line, `$0`, to `new`.
4. `1` is awk's shorthand for print-the-line.

Comment: Thank you it works! I've only two issues: the first one is that it says if I want to overwrite the file; is it possible to override that alert? And the second one is that I want to prevent to overwrite the begin of the line so "5000 = " needs to stay

Comment: "...says if I want to overwrite the file"  That sounds like you have an alias for `mv` which adds the `-i` option.  If that is the case, add the `-f` option to override: `awk -v new="NewValue" -v line=3 'NR==line{$0=new} 1' file >tmp && mv -f tmp file`

Comment: "...the line so "5000 = " needs to stay".  In that case try `awk -v new="NewValue" -v line=3 'NR==line{$0=line" = "new} 1'` or `awk -v new="NewValue" -v line=3 'NR==line{$0=$1" "$2" "new} 1' file`.  If those don't work, please clarify exactly what the original version of that line looks like.